# Minimization and integration

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How do I get the minimum numerical of y = the integration of (8 d (h^2 m^2 + 2 d (2 A + d) k^2 n^2 Sin[x]^4) Sin[k n (-q + x)]^2)/(
 h^2 (-4 d (2 A + d) + h^2 Cot[x]^2)) + (
 d k^2 n^2 Sin[2 x]^2 Sin[k n (-q + x)]^2)/(
 4 d (2 A + d) - h^2 Cot[x]^2) - (
 8 d k n Cos[x]^3 Sin[x] Sin[2 k n (-q + x)])/(
 4 d (2 A + d) - h^2 Cot[x]^2) - (
 32 d^2 (2 A + d) k n Cos[x] Sin[x]^3 Sin[2 k n (-q + x)])/(
 h^2 (-4 d (2 A + d) + h^2 Cot[x]^2)) with respect to x from q to pi-q. Where d = 4, h = 20, A = 10, t = 0.1, q = 1.19029, k = 4.128173459, m = 1, n is an integer and is between 2 and 150 inclusive. Thanks

Comment: Assign the values to your constants, t isn't used, Simplify and see the result is substantially smaller with far fewer denominators. Then, since you require n to be integer and want the minimum, calculate a Table with each of the 149 values of n and select the smallest one.

Comment: Thank you @Bill. Yes, there is not t here. I have simplified it to (d ((16 d (2 A + d) k^2 n^2 Sin[x]^4 + 
        h^2 (8 m^2 - k^2 n^2 Sin[2 x]^2)) Sin[k n (-q + x)]^2 + 
     2 k n (-8 A d - 4 d^2 + 
        h^2 + (8 A d + 4 d^2 + h^2) Cos[2 x]) Sin[2 x] Sin[
       2 k n (-q + x)]))/(h^2 (-4 d (2 A + d) + h^2 Cot[x]^2)). If it is possible to write a simple code for obtaining the minimum integral, please assist. I dont want to do the integration one-by-one for the 149 different values of n. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

for this case it is actually quite reasonable to crunch out the solution for every `n`:

```
results = Table[{n, NIntegrate[..., {x, q, Pi - q}]}, {n, 2, 150}]
MinimalBy[results, #[[2]] &]
```

> {{150, -5311.7}}

the result is monotonically decreasing so will always be minimum at the max `n`.

Comment: I am very grateful. Thank you....you guys are wonderful!